# Excel pre-defined Styles keep coming back

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, ribbon

MS Excel, MS Home and Business 2016.
Looking at the ribbon, Home Tab, "Styles box", on a full width screen.

I see "Conditional Formatting", "Format as Table" and then a bunch of pre-defined Styles available to just click on.

By default, in the first few rows, I have a bunch of "60% Accent" options, and then "Neutral 2" (yellow/orange) and "Title 2" (blue on white) etc. etc.

---

In my particular Sheet, I've defined some custom stylings, and saved those stylings. Now those stylings show up in the "Styles" grid, so that I can easily re-use them. Great!

It's annoying that they're not at the top of the Styles box, so I right-click on some of the pre-built ones and choose "Delete". They go away. Now my custom styles are the ones at the top of the box. Whoopee! Success!

And now I save and close my sheet and re-open it. Styles box still looks as it did when I closed the sheet. Hooray!

So far everything is behaving exactly as I would hope / expect.

---

The trouble is, this is at least the 4th time I've gone through the process of removing the "irrelevant" styles - they keep coming back. I don't know what causes them - I haven't got a way to forcibly reproduce it :(

What's going on, and can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Your custom styles should appear at the top of the "Styles" grid in any case. The order of the sections in my grid are: "Custom", "Good, Bad and Neutral", "Data and Model", "Titles and Headings", "Themed Cell Styles" (this is the section you are trying to delete), "Number Format". I'm not particularly surprised that the default sections keep coming back, but you shouldn't need to delete then as the "Custom" section should be at the top anyway.

Comment: @Bla ooh, interesting ... I don't normally click on the "More" arrow on the bottom right. Clicking on that, I get the same sub-sections you've listed there. I'll take a look at what in them, then next time it goes screwy.